# Closed form expression of following equation

Tags: summation-method

Can someone hint me on solving the following equation to find $P^*$

\begin{equation}
P^* =\sum^\infty_{n=m}\{P(m).P(R_{n\mid m} \}
\end{equation}

Where,
\begin{equation}
P(m) = e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^m / m!
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(R_{n\mid m}) = \sum^{n}_{j=0}(-1)^jC^j_n(1 - j.\phi)^m
\end{equation}

The final solution is as follows:

\begin{equation}
P^* = (1 - e^{-\phi\lambda t})^n
\end{equation}

NOTE: It is not a part of any exam or assignment, I am reading a resarch paper. and I have never solved equations where I have Summation of such peculiar terms...If someone doesnot want to give the whole solution,any hint would still be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is $\lambda_{1,a}$? Is it real or complex?

Comment: It is a real value. It is a parameter of the exponential distribution. I have edited it to make it simplified form

Comment: You are simply supposed to note that $$P^*=\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^m}{m!}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}(1-j\phi)^m$$ is $$P^*=e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(\lambda t)^m}{m!}(1-j\phi)^m=e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}e^{\lambda t(1-j\phi)}$$ that is, $$P^*=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}e^{-j\lambda t\phi}=(1-e^{-\lambda t\phi})^n$$ Note the serious misprint in your formula for $P^*$, which should involve $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty$$ instead of $$\sum_{n=m}^\infty$$

Comment: Thanks Did for the solution, Can you please give me some reference or know how the way you simplified the respective terms to $e^{\lambda t (1-j\phi)}$. and the other term to $(1 - e^{-\lambda t n})^n$.

Thanks. Also, although I am pretty sure after reading the paper that it should start from $n=m$ and author also does the same equation as I have quoted. I will have a look at it. Thanks again